# Firebase function use outside file from react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-functions

I just init my firebase functions folder inside a react app folder

```
myproject
 +- .firebaserc             
 |
 +- firebase.json  
 |
 +- functions/
 |
 +- src/
      +- services/
      +- package.json  
      +- App.tsx
```

In my services folder(react-app) i have some method who call external api

I want to reuse this file in my cloud functions to share code between react app and cloud functions

How to perform that properly ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy fix would be just make the code more of a util, then import the function with path, and use it in firebase-function.
Or you can change the path of the function folder updating the `firebase.json` file using `"source": "public"` or any dir you want to use.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "source": "public"
  }
}
```

Comment: I just add "source" : "" and it's